# mvc3 web grid number/decimal formatting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How can I format the following and specify the number of decimal places in an mvc3/asp.net/webgrid?

```
grid.Column("Val", format: @<text>@((decimal)100/3) </text>)
```

Thx!

Comment: Does anybody know how I could have used casting and conversion instead of using a code block as such???  

grid.Column("W2", format: @<text>@{string ss=(
                   (decimal) ((decimal)50 / 102)  ).ToString("#.000000");
           } @ss</text>),

Comment: why not do the formatting of the field in the controller, passing a ready-made value for the view to just display?

Comment: @nathangonzalez: Probably could have and would probably prefer it but might due to MVC ignorance and because the value is in a result set (not being calculated once).  I thought it (the view doing the work) would suffice and pass in the resultset.ToList() and massage the data in the view.  Again, more of ignorance on using the MVC on my part and using stock out of the box views.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can format decimal values in C# as so:

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4567);      // "123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4);         // "123.40"
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.0);         // "123.00"
```

Given the above, you should be able to do:

```
grid.Column("Val", format: @<text>@String.Format("{0:0.00}", (decimal)(100/3)) </text>)
```

More information on formatting decimal, doubles and floats: http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/